# Custom Fields affecting Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I've been trying to put custom fields into my posts on Wordpress, however whenever I put on **this code** onto my file, the post, custom field, and the content and code that goes after the supposed custom field does not run

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'instagram', true); ?>
```

As well as this one

```
<?php 
        $instagram = get_post_meta($post=>ID, 'Instagram', true);
        if($instagram){ ?>
            <p>@sample.handle</p>
        <?php
        }else{ }
        ?>
```

I also tried putting both on other themes even on Twenty Twenty and it still doesn't work. Even tried ACF but still nothing.

Would really appreciate the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing out your HTML instead of closing and opening the php as I think that is breaking the php function as it would be mixing its ends statements.

```
<?php 
        $instagram = get_post_meta($post=>ID, 'Instagram', true);
        if($instagram){ 
           echo '<p>@sample.handle</p>';

        }else{ }
        ?>
```

Comment: It's still not working :( It's running some codes before the tag though but it's still not showing after it

Comment: Can you enable debugging by adding this to a php script function that is working or add a new one bore your code runs? This should help pin point the error. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: This code (ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);) worked, but only when I tried using get_field (which I eventually remembered was only enabled with ACF lol because of the script you provided). The post is now running with ACF enabled unlike earlier but only posts with values filled in are showing (hope that makes sense).

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you resolve the issue.